# Solr returning docs on empty query - How to stop?

Tags: solr

```
<!-- Search -->
<div class="searchresults">
    <div>
        <div class="searchresultsinput">
            @Html.TextBox("query-box", Model.Search.FreeSearch)
            <input type="image" id="search-btn" class="search-btn" onclick="ExecuteSearch(); return false;" src='@Html.IncludeCDNImagePathWithTimeStamp("Buttons/search-now.png")' />
        </div>
        <div class="searchresultscounts">
            @{
                if (Model.TotalCount > 0)
                {
                    if (Model.Search.LastItemIndex > Model.TotalCount)
                    {
                        <div>Showing @(Model.Search.FirstItemIndex + 1) - @Model.TotalCount of @Model.TotalCount documents.</div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div>Showing @(Model.Search.FirstItemIndex + 1) - @Model.Search.LastItemIndex of @Model.TotalCount documents.</div>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DidYouMean))
                    {
                        <span>Did you mean </span><strong><em><a href="<%= Url.ForQuery(Model.DidYouMean) %>"><%= Model.DidYouMean%></a></em></strong>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div>No results found. Please try a different search term.</div>
                    }
                }
            }

        </div>
```

I have three Solr Instances on Internal QA Environment and Two on Production. All of them are almost configuration wise identical. The problem is Solr is returning search results even when nothing is typed in the search box field? [Search Button on the Website]

Can anyone please help as to what I need to do at Solr level to stop this from happening. I wanna be able to display a message stating "You Search Enter 0 Results" if somebody tries to hit the search button with an empty query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not Solr which is returning docs on empty query. I'm quite sure you're sending some query to Solr like "templateid: someId" or even something more.

What you need to do is to check in your frontend if user typed anything in the box (or in the backend but before the call to Solr is even called) and display the correct message to the user.

However without seeing the code you're using to populate search result list, no one will be able to give you exact code you need.

---

**EDIT**

Your html contains `onclick="ExecuteSearch(); return false;"`.

Change your `ExecuteSearch` function and add a check if the `query-box` input value is not empty. If it's empty, don't send request to Solr.

Comment: Actually, SOLR typically sends everything to the client (within it's default document limit of 100) - it is only when you add filters and queries, the results are narrowed down.

Comment: Yes, but OP wrote "even when nothing is typed in the search box field". Solr has nothing to do with the search box. Is the frontend/backend logic behind the search functionality on that page.

Comment: Edit you question instead of adding comment

Comment: Marek: Thanks for your input. Can you give me sample code on how to do it? actually, I'm not much into coding so that's why need some help here. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

If your business rule is to show 0 results when nothing is typed, you should handle this behavior in the view or server layer, **before** your server hits Solr, and don't hit it at all.